# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound when using VSCode, but no error when running directly from Virtual Environment

Tags: python, jinja2

I was trying to follow a [tutorial to Create Cisco Router configs using Jinja2](https://blogs.cisco.com/developer/network-configuration-template) -- and python only uses Jinja2 as a template processor.

I have a python file:

```
from jinja2 import FileSystemLoader, Environment


env = Environment(loader = FileSystemLoader('.'))
template = env.get_template('hworld.j2')
print(template.render())
```

And have a jinja2 template:

```
Hello, World!
```

I'm however getting an exception while trying to execute the python file from within the terminal of VSCode:

```
(env) som@lappyPrime:~/GNS3/projects/IPSec_basic1$ /home/som/GNS3/projects/IPSec_basic1/auto/env/bin/python3 /home/som/GNS3/projects/IPSec_basic1/auto/Sys_info.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/som/GNS3/projects/IPSec_basic1/auto/Sys_info.py", line 6, in <module>
    template = env.get_template('hworld.j2')
  File "/home/som/GNS3/projects/IPSec_basic1/auto/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 883, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/home/som/GNS3/projects/IPSec_basic1/auto/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 857, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "/home/som/GNS3/projects/IPSec_basic1/auto/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 115, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "/home/som/GNS3/projects/IPSec_basic1/auto/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 197, in get_source
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: hworld.j2
```

The same code runs flawlessly when I directly enter the virtual env from a terminal and execute it:

```
(env) som@lappyPrime:~/GNS3/projects/IPSec_basic1/auto$ ls -l
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 6 som som 4096 Oct 30 14:10 env
-rw-rw-r-- 1 som som   76 Oct 30 14:42 env_info.j2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 som som   13 Oct 30 14:42 hworld.j2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 som som  348 Oct 30 14:43 Sys_info.py
(env) som@lappyPrime:~/GNS3/projects/IPSec_basic1/auto$ python Sys_info.py 
Hello, World!
(env) som@lappyPrime:~/GNS3/projects/IPSec_basic1/auto$ which python
/home/som/GNS3/projects/IPSec_basic1/auto/env/bin/python
(env) som@lappyPrime:~/GNS3/projects/IPSec_basic1/auto$ pip list
Package           Version
----------------- -------
astroid           2.4.2  
isort             5.6.4  
Jinja2            2.11.2 
lazy-object-proxy 1.4.3  
MarkupSafe        1.1.1  
mccabe            0.6.1  
pip               20.0.2 
pkg-resources     0.0.0  
pylint            2.6.0  
setuptools        44.0.0 
six               1.15.0 
toml              0.10.1 
wrapt             1.12.1
```

Why does this happen? I can see that VSCode is running the program from within the virtual env!

FYI -- [here's what my env looks like, under VSCode terminal.](https://pastebin.com/V3fNA5Uu)

Comment: Being honest, the terminal under VSCode sometimes behaves really strange. I had problems with pytest previously. Even though VSCode discovered the right pytest script to run (incl. all plugins), it failed to work properly. I only solved it by giving the full path to pytest in the workspace settings. I'm not sure, if this helps, but in fact, you're more save when using the normal terminal application.

Comment: @ThomasKlinger Putting `"python.pythonPath": "/home/som/GNS3/projects/IPSec_basic1/auto/env/bin/python"` in settings.json didn't help either!